# Understanding where 'creation time', 'accessed time' , 'modified time', etc are saved in a file in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

This is part of my job and spent over a week understanding the timestamps.

I could open a file in hex editor. But I cannot understand where the timestamps are stored.

Request anyone to help me, I am totally stuck in understanding it.

Comment: The question is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These information are not stored in the file itself, hence you can't find them inside.
Those information are metadata, that are stored in respective datastructures of the underlying file-system, which is for your windows probably [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS).

To access these meta-data you can use [CLI tools from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928644/how-to-get-creation-date-of-file-on-windows-command-line)

Comment: thanks a lot for replying as it is important for me. But when i copy a file from one computer to another, modified time remains same. It means, that information must be in the file, isn't it? (if it was in the underlying file-system, modified data cannot be same, correct?)

Comment: They are not in the file. The operating system (Windows) preserves the information to the new destination, by setting the appropriate information in the destination's file system. So it access them from the origin and saves them in the destination.

Comment: oh, this is what confused me. thanks you saved my time.

Comment: one more thing puzzles me. if i copy a file to pen drive and later to another computer from the pen drive, modified date remains same. When the file is in pen drive, no operating system and modified date cannot be saved according to your answer. Am i missing something?

Comment: You need to understand the natur of a file-system, in this case NTFS. A file-system is a data-structure that "you cant see" as the operating-system (Windows) abstracts and hides it from you. So if you copy a file to an external memory, windows copies the meta-data (creation time, access time etc) to the file system on the external drive. So apart from the file itself, Windows writes those data addionally to the file system. But not in the file itself.